# What is the difference between array parameters in C

Tags: c, arrays, return-value, argument-passing

what is the difference between following function declarations, which create and return the array in C/C++? Both methods create the array and fill it with proper values and returns true if everything passed.

```
bool getArray(int* array);
bool getArray(int* array[]);
```

Thanks

Best Regards,
STeN

Comment: How would the first one return a new array? Have you missed an asterisk when creating the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps you to think about it you can remember that `int foo[]` is the same thing as `int *foo` at one level.  So in your example the first is passed a pointer to an int while the second is passed a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Comment: Just to clarify: `int foo[]` and `int *foo` are equivalent *in the context of function parameters*.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks - this really help solving my problem. I am normally using only C++ or Objective-C with special container classes for everything and each time I am doing th pure C I fall in troubles
for few days until I get on the right path:((

The right questing should be: What is the difference between

<code>bool getArray(int** array);</code> and
<code>bool getArray(int* array[]);</code>

I think (hopefully correctly) there there is no difference...

Thanks all you guys for help.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

`bool getArray(int *array);` takes a pointer to an int as an argument (effectively an array of ints to fill).  `bool getArray(int *array[]);`takes an array of int pointers.  The first one is the one you want, though the caller will need to allocate a sufficiently large output array so `getArray()` can copy the array elements into it.

One way to understand C pointer/array declarations is to think of them as illustrating how to access the base type.  `int *array` means that if you say `*array`, you'll get an int.  `int *array[]` means if you say `*array[x]`, you'll get an int.  `char (*array)[5][2][3]` means if you say `(*array)[0 thru 4][0 thru 1][0 thru 2]`, you'll get a char.

Comment: If I were doing it, I'd probably do `int *getArray()` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, the code you posted is C++. There's no such thing as "C/C++"... What makes your prototypes recognizable as C++-conformant is the use of the data type "bool" for the functions' return types. Boolean variables aren't defined in C.

Comment: "bool" was added to C in C99, although you have to #include <stdbool.h> to get it.

Answer (score 0):

The second requires a pointer to an array. So if you the array is `int *getme;` then you call `getArray(&getme);`

Comment: No, the second requires an array of pointers.  A pointer to an array would be `int (*array)[]`.